# Invariant Violation: ListView has been removed. But

Tags: react-native, react-redux, version

I have this code from courses, and how I understand my mistake, that ListView has been removed from ReactNative. How can I fix the problem?

I've tried to replace all ListView  tag to FlatList. But didn't work out.

```
class LibraryList extends Component {
 componentWillMount() {
   const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
 });

  this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.libraries);
 }

renderRow(library) {
  return <ListItem library={library} />;
}

render() {
  return (
   <ListView
     dataSource={this.dataSource}
     renderRow={this.renderRow}
    />
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you convert it correctly to flatlist? changing `dataSource` to `data` and `renderRow` to `renderItem`?

Comment: Yes, now it's working) data={this.props.libraries}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(library) => library.title}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class LibraryList extends Component{
    renderRow({item}) {
        return <ListItem library = { item } />;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <FlatList
                data = {this.props.libraries}
                renderItem = {this.renderRow}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no ListView component but it's still getting back the invariant violation error react native

Answer (score 17):

List VIew is deprecated in react native 0.60. So the quick fix is to use deprecated-react-native-listview

Need to add

**import ListView from "deprecated-react-native-listview";**

instead of

**import ListView from from 'react-native';**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deprecated-react-native-listview

Comment: I have no ListView component but it's still getting back the invariant violation error react native

Comment: then it should be coming from another decency  in node_modules like in "react-native-modal-dropdown" you need to make changes in package file

Comment: did you find any solution!

Comment: if you didint use ListView Component then it should be coming from another library so for that either you have to make changes to package.json of that library or report to owner of library to make changes to package.json so that you dont have to do it every time. if possible share error log